# Directions are backwards opening apple maps

Tags: swift

Hi I have functioning and updated code where I pass in an address for pickup from a server through coordinates. However, when this opens up Apple Maps, the directions are backwards. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I have tried to change my param and how the address is pulled but no luck.

```
func openAppleMaps(location : CLLocationCoordinate2D){
    let appleMapsURL = URL(string: "http://maps.apple.com");
    if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appleMapsURL!)) {

        var directionRequestURL = appleMapsURL!.relativeString
        let param1 = "?daddr=" + "\(location.latitude)" + "," + "\(location.longitude)"
        let param2 = "&saddr=" + "\(LocationManager.shared.locationManager.location!.coordinate.latitude)" + "," + "\(LocationManager.shared.locationManager.location!.coordinate.longitude)" + "&dirflg=d"
        directionRequestURL += param1 + param2
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: directionRequestURL)!, options: convertToUIApplicationOpenExternalURLOptionsKeyDictionary([:]), completionHandler: nil);
    }
}
```

I need to have the current location being shown and the address we are going to to be displayed. Not backwards. Thanks

Comment: `MKMapItem` has methods for opening apple maps that would be better than trying to manually build a URL

Comment: are you deffo using `saddr` for the start address and `daddr` for the destination? - hard to tell by looking at your code.

Comment: yes I am i would hope to keep this the same

Comment: Have you printed your `directionRequestURL` to make sure it is being built correctly before opening it? `print(directionRequestURL)` - is it possible your LocationManager isn't getting your location correctly?

Comment: @Wez for example I am going from madison square garden to soho new york. Here is my API.             latitude = "40.7505";
                "location_id" = 990862;
                "long_name" = "Madison Square Garden, 4 Pennsylvania Plaza, New York, NY 10001, USA";
                longitude = "-73.99343"; latitude = "40.7233";
            "location_id" = 925039;
            "long_name" = "SoHo, New York, NY, USA";
            longitude = "-74.00297999999999"; I am not sure where to look.

Comment: What does this output: `print(directionRequestURL)`

Comment: Here is the url "http://maps.apple.com?daddr=40.7505,-73.99343&saddr=40.758896,-73.98513&dirflg=d"

Comment: @Wez I hope this helps